# lValue required as left Operand of Assignment

Tags: objective-c, ios4, sdk

I'm trying to UnArchive into an `NSMutableArray`. This statement gives me an 'Lvalue required as left operand of assignment'

```
[[[VariableStore sharedInstance] riskValues] = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self archivePath]]];
```

The `NSMutableArray` is declared in the `VariableStore` singleton.  Any ideas, anyone please?

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign values like that, you would need a setter method...

```
[[VariableStore sharedInstance]setRiskValues:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self archivePath]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a setter:

```
[VariableStore sharedInstance].riskValues = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self archivePath]];
```

Or:

```
[[VariableStore sharedInstance] setRiskValues:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self archivePath]]];
```

Comment: Just a helpful note for anyone doing something similar: The first form requires the return value of `+[VariableStore sharedInstance]` to be statically typed. If it returns `id`, you have to use the second one (or cast the return value, but good grief, how much effort does setting this property *deserve*?).